# Is it possible to add data to the details of an alarm?

Tags: alarm, thingsboard, telemetry

I have created an alarm for when a certain device outputs an error.
because i have a very large amount of alarms for different errors i made them in the device profile page and not in the rule chain.

In the docs i found [this](https://thingsboard.io/docs/user-guide/device-profiles/) where it states

> Details - the alarm details template supports substitution of the telemetry and/or attribute values using ${attributeName} syntax;

but this only works for the telemetry and/or attribute of the alarm.
for example:

An alarm has been set when temp exceeds 20°C. You can now put ${temp} in the details. but i would also like to add "air humidity".

Is it possible to add EXTRA data to the details?

Answer (score 0):

The only workaround I found is to put humidity in the query.
E.g. when temp exceeds 20 and humidity >= 0.